# How to solve ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative without updating the list size in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of color names having total 36 color names like below-

```
MAIN_COLORS = ['darkolivegreen', 'darkseagreen', 'darkorange', 'darkslategrey', 'darkturquoise', 'darkgreen', 'darkviolet', 'darkgray', 'darkmagenta', 'darkblue', 'darkkhaki','darkcyan', 'darkred',  'darksalmon', 'darkslategray', 'darkgoldenrod', 'darkgrey', 'darkslateblue', 'darkorchid','skyblue','yellow','orange','red','pink','violet','green','brown','gold','Olive','Maroon', 'blue', 'cyan', 'black','olivedrab', 'lightcyan', 'silver']
```

And I have a classes.txt file having total 459 labels.

Now when I run below code snippet-

```
try:
with open('classes.txt','r') as cls:
    classes = cls.readlines()
classes = [cls.strip() for cls in classes]
except IOError as io:
  print("[ERROR] Please create classes.txt and put your all classes")
  sys.exit(1)
COLORS = random.sample(set(MAIN_COLORS), len(classes))
```

I am getting below error-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/Projects/YoloV3_Annotation_Tool-master/YoloV3_Annotation_Tool-master/main.py", line 42, in 
>       COLORS = random.sample(set(MAIN_COLORS), len(classes))
>     File "C:\Users\prateek.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myNewEnv\lib\random.py", line 321, in sample
>       raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
>   ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

From the error I understand that I need to increase the color names in my list but it seems difficult to add colors since number of labels in classes may increase.

So is there any way I can fix this problem? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand your MAIN_COLORS list by adding it to itself as many times as needed.

for example:

```
while len(MAIN_COLORS)<len(classes):
    MAIN_COLORS = MAIN_COLORS + MAIN COLORS
```

However it will create duplicated values in your list, and you have used set() in your code, so no matter how many times you will duplicate your list, set() will decrease its size to main.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought the same way. Just hoping there will be a better solution.